# How to get all products using category ID in zen cart?

Tags: php, zen-cart

I am new to zen cart , i tried several forums but couldn't get on how to fetch all the products using the category id. So can we get all the products using the category id in zen cart using some zen cart inbuilt functions?

Comment: Do you want to get them through php? Have you tried it with a sql statement in your favorite sql editor?

Comment: I was looking for some zen cart built in functions, so that i can get all the related details in a single array

Comment: Ok, please add this detail to your question. I don't know if there is a function like that.